# visual studio 2017 evaluation period expired on a PC not connected to internet

Tags: visual-studio

I installed VS Studio 2017 community on a computer that is not connected to the internet. Now I got the message  that my "evaluation period has ended!.

I know that this problem goes away if I sign in. But I am on a computer that is not to be connected to the internet. What can I do to solve this problem?